# changing defaults when generating new SSH server keys

Tags: openssh, ssh-host-key

On Debian, I can generate new SSH server keys:

```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

but that will generate the keys with default values, ie `2048` RSA key.

What is happening under the hood, when I execute `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` ?

How can I change these defaults (ie, rsa to `4096`), when generateing new server keys ?

Comment: i don't know about debian, but in ubuntu, you just delete the keys from the authorized_keys file, and insert a new 4096 key in it's place.

Comment: @keithRozario – This question is asking about server keys, not client keys. @​mti2935 made the same mistake in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Run this (as root) instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

# clean up old keys or complain you're not root
cd /etc/ssh && rm ssh_host_*key* || echo "Run this as root!" >&2 && exit 2

# generate; see https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ssh_host_ed25519_key -N "" < /dev/null
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ssh_host_rsa_key -N "" < /dev/null

# zero for untrusted keys (prevents their recreation with dpkg-reconfigure)
touch ssh_host_dsa_key ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# restart ssh
service ssh restart
```

I disabled DSA (which is [highly insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855045/519360)) and ECDSA (which has less worrisome risks, see prior link or [Secure Secure Shell](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html)).

`dpkg-reconfigure` will not touch your pre-existing keys (I see you recognized this, that's why you ran `rm` first). In fact, it's not even necessary to reconfigure; a simple `service ssh restart` should suffice.

If do this manually, you can preserve your existing ed25519 key; the defaults are good for it.

---

All clients' `~/.ssh/known_hosts` files for this host will now all be wrong. You can just replace the matching entry after the first space with the new .pub file or re-verify the signatures. I do that with `ssh localhost` on the server (and I always say "no") to get the hash, but the "right" way to do it is:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command will generate a 4096-bit RSA keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

See then [man page for ssh-keygen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) for more info.